# Product of elementary matrices - how to prove that as short as possible

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to write the matrix $\mathbf A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}$ as a product of elementary matrices, using as few as I can. However, I don't know how to prove that my expression is as short as possible?

For example, after manipulating algorithmically, I got that
A = (clockwise entries): 1,0,3,1 * 1,0,0,-2 * 1,2,0,1.

How to prove that this is short as possible though?

Comment: It is pretty clear that you can't get your matrix A by performing only two elementary row operations on I; so any product of 3 elementary matrices that give A will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown $A$ can be written using three operations. It suffices you show there is no possible pair $E_1,E_2$ of elementary matrices such that $A=E_1E_2$.

Comment: Sure. I did that, but how do I prove that it is as short as possible?

Comment: @AbhishekMallela I have misread your question. Let me edit.

Comment: Oh no, that wasn't me.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks.